# mysql ndb cluster add data node

Tags: mysql, file, configuration, for-loop, cluster-computing

This is my config.ini file

## options affecting ndbd processes on all data nodes:

[ndbd default]
NoOfReplicas=1    # Number of replicas
DataMemory=80M    # How much memory to allocate for data storage
IndexMemory=18M   # How much memory to allocate for index storage
                  # For DataMemory and IndexMemory, we have used the
                  # default values. Since the "world" database takes up
                  # only about 500KB, this should be more than enough for
                  # this example Cluster setup.

## TCP/IP options:

[tcp default]
portnumber=2202   # This the default; however, you can use any port that is free 
                  # for all the hosts in the cluster
                  # Note: It is recommended that you do not specify the port 
                  # number at all and allow the default value to be used instead

## Management process options:

[ndb_mgmd]
hostname=192.168.1.10           # Hostname or IP address of management node
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster  # Directory for management node log files

## Options for data node "A":

[ndbd]
                                # (one [ndbd] section per data node)
hostname=192.168.1.10           # Hostname or IP address
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data   # Directory for this data node's data files

## Options for data node "B":

[ndbd]
hostname=192.168.0.20           # Hostname or IP address
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data   # Directory for this data node's data files

## SQL node options:

[mysqld]
hostname=192.168.1.10           # Hostname or IP address
                                # (additional mysqld connections can be
                                # specified for this node for various
                                # purposes such as running ndb_restore)

I want to specify second data node on 192.168.0.20 server.
What changes do i need to do on 192.168.0.20? It is a very low end machine so, I want don't want mysqld to run there.
 can anyone provide any input on this.

Answer (score 2):

If you use http://www.severalnines.com/config/index.php to create configurations files, and ask it to send it to you as an e-mail, you will get several scripts, including add_node.sh, which might be what you need.